# Error al obtener query en node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy haciendo para mí una agenda (sin seguridad alguna). Para añadir, borrar o actualizar utilizo **GET** para avisar al servidor de que estoy añadiendo una tarea. La dirección sería esta:

> http://127.0.0.1:3690/update?start=1536624000&title=Rellenar%20agenda&content=Finalizar%20la%20agrnda&end=1537488000&by=josem&to=Josem&priority=0&color=#FF0000&qid=5&status=aceptado

Después, para obtener el query en node.js, uso este código:

```
if (url_parts.pathname == "/update") {           
    var start = url_parts.query.start;
    var end = url_parts.query.end;
    var status = url_parts.query.status;
    var by = url_parts.query.by;
    var title = url_parts.query.title;
    var content = url_parts.query.content;
    var to = url_parts.query.to;
    var priority = url_parts.query.priority;
    var color = url_parts.query.color;
    var qid = url_parts.query.qid;
    db.run("UPDATE todo SET id="+qid+",start="+start+",end="+end+",title=\""+title+"\", content=\""+content+"\", status=\""+status+"\", importance="+priority+", user=\""+to+"\", by=\""+by+"\", color=\""+color+"\" WHERE id="+qid);
    res.end();
}
```

La función update funciona perfectamente. El único problema, es que los dos nuevos campos que he añadido hoy (*qid y status*) devuelven *undefined*. El error persiste tras reiniciar el ordenador y node. ¿Que puede causar el problema? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Quizás es demasiado básico lo que añadiré, ¿pero reiniciaste la aplicación?

Comment: Claro, y también lo probé en otro ordenador pero sigue dando el problema.

Comment: ¿podrías enviar la función completa por favor? Antes del if

Comment: Acabo de solucionar el problema. El # en la solicitud (`&color=#ff0000`) daba el error y no enviaba la solicitud completa. ¡Muchas gracias ValVert por intentar solucionarlo!

Comment: Efectivamente, hice la misma prueba pero cambiando el orden de envío. Como ya tenía listo igual colocaré la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El caracter `#` en la solicitud `(&color=#ff0000)` daba el error y no enviaba la solicitud completa.

Muchas gracias al usuario `ValVert` por intentar solucionarlo.

Comment: Hola JoséM, en tu respuesta detectas el problema. (Lo cual está muy bien), pero ¿qué has hecho para solucionarlo? Has suprimido el carácter # o quizás lo has escapado? Lo que hayas hecho quizás puede ayudar a futuros lectores, o quizás alguien pueda darte una mejor solución. Saludos.

Comment: Hola José. He suprimido directamente el carácter en la URL y he añadido el `#` directamente en el código, con `var color = "#" + url_parts.query.color`.